# Ruby rails. Undefined method error, creating nested resource object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, resources, nested, nomethoderror

I am trying to render a form to upload a song. 
I have a playlist model and a song model, song being a nested resource of playlist.

With simple form, when I try and render the new song partial, I get  `undefined method songs_path for #<#<Class:0x007fdc51980870>`
In routes, the new song path is `new_playlist_song` but it doesn't seem that simple form knows this.

Songs controller:

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController


  def new
      @song = Song.new
  end

  def create
    @song = Song.new(song_params)
    if @song.save
      flash[:info] = "Song uploaded sensually"
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def index
    @song = Song.all
  end

  private

    def song_params
      params.require(:song).permit(:audio)
  end

end
```

Playlists controller:

```
class PlaylistsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_playlist, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]


  def index
    @playlists = Playlist.all
  end

  def new
    if user_signed_in?
    @playlist = current_user.playlists.new
  else
     redirect_to(root_url)
     flash[:danger] = "You have to register to purchase gigs"
   end
  end

  def create
    @playlist = current_user.playlists.new
    @playlist.user_id = current_user.id
    if @playlist.save
      redirect_to new_playlist_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
     @playlist = Playlist.find(params[:id])
     if @playlist.present?
       @playlist.destroy
       redirect_to playlists_path
  end
  end


  private

  def find_playlist
    @playlist = Playlist.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

Song model:

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :playlist
  has_attached_file :audio
  validates_attachment_presence :audio
  validates_attachment_content_type :audio, :content_type => [ 'audio/mp3','audio/mpeg']


end
```

Playlist model :

```
class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :songs
end
```

Routes:

```
resources :playlists do
    resources :songs
  end
```

User profile link to create new song:

```
<p> <%= @user.playlist.user_id %> </p>
  <p> <%= @user.playlist.created_at %> </p>
<% if @user == current_user %>
  <p> <%= link_to "Uploaad track", new_playlist_song_path(@user) %>
<% end %>
```

I have tried a few variants for the simple_form form.
New song partial 1:

```
<%= simple_form_for ([@playlist, @song]) do |f| %>
<%= f.file_field :audio %>
 <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

another try :

```
<%= simple_form_for ([@playlist, current_user.playlist.songs.build]) do |f| %>
```

I just can't get the form to show and I can't figure out why not. Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I don't see "songs_path" anywhere in your code

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments `songs_path` is not referenced in your code, and shouldn't even exist as it's a sub-resource of `playlist`.
If you want to list all the available routes just run a `rake routes` and make sure the code references an existing path.

Comment: I am aware that songs_path doesn't exist, and that I haven't specified songs_path anywhere.  I don't know why simple forms is trying to find songs_path, as the actual path is new_playlist_song_path. How can I make simple form point to this instead of song_path? I have added ':url => new_playlist_song_path' but this doesn't work either.

Comment: Ok take a look here https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models it talks about dealing with nested resources with simple forms

Answer (score 0):

I didn't define the playlist that the song belongs to.

Adding      to the controller

```
def create
    @song = current_user.playlist.songs.new song_params
    @song.playlist_id = @playlist.id
    if @song.save
```

and

```
def find_playlist
    @playlist = Playlist.find(params[:id])
  end
```

then to simple form

```
<%= simple_form_for ([@playlist, @playlist.songs.build]) do |f| %>
```

It works.